# How to check mimetype from uploaded file in php

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

i have an mimetype check in my upload function, that checking if the uploaded file is an image or not.
I want to allow upload image AND pdf files, but i dont know how to change my function.

```
$verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$f]);
            $pattern = "#^(image/)[^\s\n<]+$#i";
            if(!preg_match($pattern, $verifyimg['mime']))
            {
                $err;
            }
```

I hope anybody can tell me how i need to change the $pattern varaible to check images AND pdf files.

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: That's not enough code for us to help u

Comment: C'mon, this is hardly difficult. Something like `if(!preg_match($pattern, $verifyimg['mime']) && $verifyimg['mime'] != 'application/pdf')`

Comment: sorry but this is the only code-snipped where the filetype would be checked

Comment: thanks for your comment ceejayoz, but i get evertime the err if i try to upload a pdf file. The Image part i working fine!

Comment: Try to change your code like `application/x-pdf`...`x-pdf` might be used for compatibility with old software.

Comment: no it doesnt work. I think the problem is the !preg_match $pattern part. And why the hell this should be a duplicate Fred?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) built in function like this:

```
<?php

$file = "C:\\users\\username\\desktop\\mypic.png";

echo mime_content_type($file); // prints "image/png"
?>
```